# Internationalizing subpackages in a Python application

Tags: python, internationalization, gettext

I have an internationalized application written against Python 2.7.
In it I use a few packages I have written. I would like user-visible text in these packages to be translated.

Given that the application installs `_` into the `__builtin__` namespace with `translation.install`, how do I get the individual packages to have their text translated with their particular translations which have their own domains? Is it possible to merge two translations, for instance? Then I could just have the application merge the packages translation on import if I put it in a conventional place.

Do I have to define `_` and my other gettext helpers at the top of each subpackage? If so, how can they pick up on the application's configured language while remaining loosely coupled?

This feels like it's more complicated than it should be, which leads me to believe I'm not understanding something.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not installing `_` into builtins, but rather defining it inside your package's `__init__` and explicitly importing it in the other modules.

E.g. `mypackage/__init__.py`:

```
import gettext
translations = gettext.translation('mypackage')
_ = translations.ugettext
```

and then elsewhere

```
from mypackage import _

some_string = _("Something that will be translated")
```

I haven't actually used gettext in a long while, so take this example with a gain of salt (although it was based on the [recommendation in gettext's documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gettext#localizing-your-module)).

I've been mostly working with Zope-based web applications that cannot do the translation during module import -- we need to delay the actual translation until request rendering time, so we know the user's preferred language.  We use zope.i18nmessageid's MessageFactory to mark strings for translation in a very similar way:

```
# mypackage/__init__.py
from zope.i18nmessageid import MessageFactory
_ = MessageFactory("mypackage")

# mypackage/somemodule.py
from mypackage import _
some_string = _("Something that will be translated later")
# e.g. with print zope.i18n.translate(some_string, request)
```

Comment: This would work for an application where its packages were allowed to know about the fact that they're actually running in that application. These packages should be generic standalone packages with no knowledge of the application.
I'm actually using a lot more than just _. I'm installing __ as a lazy_gettext function so I can translate things at class level, and also the ngettext function.
So to clarify:

Comment: The app starts up. It detects the system's locale and also checks its config file to see if the user has configured a language. It imports another package, one that I have written but that should not know anything about the fact that it is running in the application, let's call this package shared_package.

If I am understanding your answer correctly you recommend then that shared_package should import the gettext helpers, _, __, and ngettext, from the application. This doesn't work, however, when shared_package is used in another application -- it shouldn't know where those come from.

Comment: I could split the internationalization initialization code out of the applications themselves into its own package and have packages which require the functionality import from it. This would be kind of ugly because it would require shared_package and similar to import from i18n_package at the top, but at least they wouldn't know specifics about what application they were running in.
I hope this clarifies things a little bit.
Thanks for your response!

Comment: You ask good questions, and I wish I knew the answers.  Perhaps have your app read its configuration file and modify `os.environ['LC_MESSAGES']` before it imports your modules?